# Unbounded and infinite set

Tags: real-analysis

> The subset $$A=\{x\in \Bbb Q:-1<x<0\}\cup\Bbb N$$ of $\Bbb R$ is:
>
> A) bounded, infininte set and has a limit point in $\Bbb R$
>
> B) unbounded, infinite set and has a limit point in $\Bbb R$
>
> C) unbounded, infinite set and does not have a limit point in $\Bbb R$
>
> D) bounded, infinite set and does not have a limit point in $\Bbb R$

I am confused between B and C.

I think B is correct option but I am not sure.

Comment: $0$ is one of the limit points. Can you show that?

Comment: Could you please explain!!

Comment: The difference is whether $A$ has or doesn't have a limit point. Do you know what a limit point is? Can you check if $A$ has one?

Comment: @user458361 yeah. As CiaPan has said, you have to know the def of limit point, can you put it down here?

Comment: A real number $l$ is said to be limit point of a set $S$ if every neighborhood of $l$ contains an infinite number of members of $S$.

Comment: Wow…dat will be a hard def to play on (we usually just say for every neighborhood of $l$, there is another distinct point of $S$)

Comment: Anyway, for any $r>0$, do you see there are infinitely many (small negative) numbers inside $B_r(0)$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know the definitions of "bounded", "infinite set" and "limit point"? Have you tried to apply those to the situation?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, you know that $A$ is unbounded and infinite, so let's focus on the limit points.

As you know,

> real number $l$ is said to be limit point of a set $S$ if every neighborhood of $l$ contains an infinite number of members of $S$

It should be relatively easy, then, to show that every number between $-1$ and $1$ is a limit point. Simply take any neighborhood of, for example, $-\frac12$, and show that the neighborhood includes elements from $A$.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is unbounded, because $\mathbb{N} \subset A$, so $A$ is infinite as well. To show that $0$ is a limit point in $A$, you need to approximate $0$ by a sequence in $A$. Define a sequence $(x_n) \subset (-1,0) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ with $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n = 0 $. This is possible, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. E.g. take $$x_n := -\frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}, n >1$. Clearly, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n = 0 $ and $x_n \in A$

Comment: It's better to use `\lim` as opposed to `lim` because it puts the letters upright. It also helps with non-inline equations, because `$$lim_{n\to\infty}$$` turns to $$lim_{n\to\infty}$$, while `$$\lim_{n\to \infty}$$` becomes $$\lim_{n\to \infty}$$